# Java JFrame access progress bar

Tags: java, jframe

I need to access my JProgressBar object from another package/class, Im trying the following

gui class

```
public class gui {

    private JProgressBar progress;

    private JFrame gui;

    public void updateBar(int value) {

        this.progress.setValue(this.progress.getValue() + value);
    }

    public void startGui() {

        // Set title, size and layout

        gui = new JFrame("Java updater");
        gui.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setResizable(false);
        gui.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        // Add elements

        elements graphics = new elements(gui);  
        this.progress = graphics.addBar(0);

        gui.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This currently works and the progressbar is beeing added but now I need to access it from another class so I can change the value of it.

I made the function updateBar but heres my problem, on my other class im doing the following

```
public class updater {

    private String domain;

    private gui bar;

    public updater() {

        this.bar = new gui();
    }

    public void updateStartup(String domain) throws MalformedURLException {

        this.domain = domain;
        URL url = new URL(this.domain);

        try {

            BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String f = read.readLine();
            System.out.println(f);
            bar.updateBar(5);

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Im calling bar.updateBar(5) with no success, getting errors.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.raggaer.gui.gui.updateBar(gui.java:17)
    at com.raggaer.updater.updater.updateStartup(updater.java:32)
    at com.raggaer.main.startup.<init>(startup.java:22)
    at com.raggaer.main.main.main(main.java:17)
```

Comment: can you past your Exception stack ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you have is that in new code you never call `startGui()` method on a newly created instance of `gui` class. Thus `private JProgressBar progress;` field in that class remains null.

You could write it like that instead as a quick fix:

```
private JProgressBar progress = new JProgressBar();
```

Or just put all code from `startGui` in a constructor of `gui` class, and get rid of `startGui` method.

Also I'd like to note that you should use `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait` or `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to call `bar.updateBar(5);` since in Swing updates to UI elements must be made in event dispatching thread (check out SwingUtilities.invokeLater documentation).

Comment: But if I add add all code into the gui consctruct I will be adding the gui elements twice , no? Edit - I did it and yeah im creating 2 forms, how should I do it show I wont make x forms ?

Comment: No. You should call new gui() once - so no duplication will occur. I'm guessing you do it like that already, since you have new gui() call in updater constructor. If you'd call it twice you had two frames anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that you have not newed up one of your classes.  My guess is that startGui in the class gui hasn't been called.

I hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

Your error say that `this.progress` is null in your call `bar.updateBar(5);`.

So that could be either because you don't launch `startGui()` function before or that `graphics.addBar(0);` return a null value.